# How should I deal with this question?

Tags: discussion

I have posted [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605674/ajax-content-is-being-loaded-but-complete-function-is-not-firing).

I have been very grateful for the help I have received particularly from iivel. Unfortunately for my particular problem I was barking up the wrong tree so to speak - turns out the ajax problems were due to an error in my PHP.

The advice given and explanations of the AJAX process were very helpful to me (although have probably been covered to death by other people.

So my question is, what do I do with this question?

I see four options:

1. Delete question - though one answer was upvoted so not sure if I can do this.
2. Answer my own question with slightly irrelevant answer explaining the situation and advising others to check the same thing.
3. Edit iivel's answer with an update and what the problem is.
4. Accept the irrelevant answer and explain in the comments.

Any advice as to what I should do here?

Comment: I've closed the question as too localized.

Comment: ok... initiative it is then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say, definitely 2.

- **Delete question** -  Deleting the question (I doubt you can do it w/o flagging it for mod attention if it has answers, but not sure) will render the time spent by the answerers useless, and will remove the 10 rep from iivel, who's help you appreciate. That's not really fair.
- **Edit iivel's answer with an update** -  You should not edit other people's posts like that. Such an edit will definitely be rejected as "invalid edit". Editing should be used to improve answers in such a way that doesn't completely change their meaning.
- **Accept irrelevant answer and explain in comments** - It is possible, but I would not do it simply because for other people that might have the same issue it will be hard to find the solution. I doubt people that are searching through questions take their time to read all comments thoroughly. Eventually they will find it of course, but it's not the best way.

If you **add your own answer** though, you will have an opportunity to explain the situation in-detail, and add the complete solution which IMO is the best way. If you feel sorry for a guy that helped you (i.e. for not accepting his answer), you can reward him as a bounty instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think it is good advice for the future, unfortunately, I have just done 3 - edited other persons answer and RH has just done 1) delete the question... still I know for next time